# how to add csrf-token to form in js

Tags: javascript, laravel

This is the code I have attempted to try and add a csrf token to a javascript form. 
but it returns "Page Expired"

```
            var form=document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method","POST");
            form.setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
            form.setAttribute("name","MyForm");
            form.setAttribute("action","AddQuestionImage");
            form.setAttribute("onsubmit","return ValidateImageExist()");
            var Input_File=document.createElement("input");
            Input_File.setAttribute("type","file");
            Input_File.setAttribute("name","question_image");

            var Token=document.createElement("input");
            Token.setAttribute("type","hidden");
            Token.setAttribute("name","_token");
            Token.setAttribute("value","{{csrf_token()}}");

            var Submit=document.createElement("input");
            Submit.setAttribute("type","submit");
            Submit.setAttribute("value","Add Image To Question");
            Submit.setAttribute("class","btn btn-warning");

            form.appendChild(Token);
            form.appendChild(Input_File);
            form.appendChild(Submit);
            Div_Control.appendChild(form);
```

Comment: Please clarify.  What doesn't work?  What does the failure look like?

Comment: Is this code being rendered directly in the page (in the view), in separate javascript file, or during an ajax call?  If you "inspect" the form after it renders, is the csrf value being set in the hidden field?  Probably start there, which will determine how to proceed with a solution.

Comment: @jon__o when i inspect the page i find every thing okay  .and i took the html which generated by the function copy and paste in html file and works fine with no errors

Comment: @EmadSayed If the source code is rendered correct with no JS errors like you said, and you are able to inspect your POST data (for example using Chrome's Inspect - Network tab) to confirm that the CSRF token is in fact included in the POST data, a "Page Expired" error would indicate a problem with your session vs a "Token Mismatch" error. Check your config/session.php settings and then clear your laravel cache `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

csrf.setAttribute("name","_token");